# Function called from from within fetch/async returns different HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json, async-await

I'm retrieving json data from a local file which I want to display using HTML. The problem is that when I call the function to create the HTML elements from within a fetch/async function, the height of the element is somehow 0.

```
function createElements(naam) {
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
var attributeDiv2 = document.createAttribute('class');
attributeDiv2.value = naam;
div2.setAttributeNode(attributeDiv2);
....
....more things
....
```

Calling from:

```
fetch("wijnen.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  for (var i = 0; i < json['Wijnen'].length; i++){
    createElements(json['Wijnen'][i].naam);
  }
});
```

Or

```
async function getData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('wijnen.json');

    let data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  }
}

(async function() {
    let data = await getData();
    console.log(data['Wijnen']);
    for (var i = 0; i < data['Wijnen'].length; i++){
      createElements(data['Wijnen'][i].naam);
    }
}());
```

Will result in

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiz54.png]

However, when I'm not calling the function from within the fetch or asynchronous function (and I pass a random string, "test" for example) it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiz54.png]

Why am I not doing it like this then? Because I can't/don't know how to access the data from the json file if I call the function outside of the fetch/async function.

The weird thing is that if I inspect the element which has height 0, I can see that the json data get's passed correctly and if I get the source code and run it locally, the height of the element isn't equal to 0 and I can see the passed json data. I run this on a server because `fetch` doesn't work locally.

Why is the height of the element equal to zero if I call the `createElements()` function from within a fetch/async function and how do I fix this?

Comment: why are you awaiting response.json() on the line that reads:
let data = await response.json();

Comment: Async is out of order execution, so the script is running before you have the elements on the page.

Comment: @Terrance response.json() returns a Promise

Comment: @serraosays using `const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));` and `await delay(2000);` at the top of the function doesn't make a difference

Comment: Confused about what is or isn't working as expected in code shown. What does the very last `console.log(data['Wijnen']);` show you? The one after `await getData()`

Comment: In the second case the `filterDiv` elements have the `show` class. In the first case they don't. I'll bet that class is used to set the `display` style.

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is that if I call `createElements()` from within the `fetch` or `async` function, the height of the element which the new created elements get appended to, becomes 0. If I don't call the `createElements()` function from within the `fetch` or `async` function, the everything works fine.

Comment: You also have two DIVs with `id="wijn_assortiment"`. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Your way of adding the class attribute to the element is strange. Just do `div2.classList.add(naam);`

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot for spotting the `show` class, that's indeed the problem. I didn't notice this because in my editor the `show` is not there because it get's added later by another function.. Also I found it strange that everything worked fine when copying the source code with inspect element and running it locally. I'm changing the id later, this was for testing only. It's strange that the `show` class get's added if I don't call the function from within `fetch`.

Comment: You're probably adding the show class in synchronous code. It needs to be added in the fetch callback.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for explaining!